# Visibility options for a whole page in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

We have reports for our school which has one page created in SSRS which is then duplicated for all students. Some students need their reports to be removed and I cannot find an option for the visibility of the whole page.

I have this code which works for visibility on individual objects within the report:

```
=iif(Fields!PupilSurname.Value = "SURNAME",
TRUE,
FALSE)
```

but is there a way to remove the whole page, rather than having to click on each individual object (of which there are a lot)? Is there a way to change this to make it work in the Custom Code of the report?

Thanks

Comment: Is the report area within a group? It seems like excluding the students from your data would be the best way to handle the requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't, the students are away on long term sick and we will need their data there when they come back.

Comment: Rob - I do not mean purge the data. You can filter the dataset either in your database or in the report itself in such a way that meets your requirements. I posted one solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like excluding the students from your data would be the best way to handle the requirement.

You can filter report groups. You should be able to add a filter condition by which only values that evaluate to true will pass thru.

You can keep this in the expression part of the filter:

```
=iif(Fields!PupilSurname.Value = "SURNAME",
TRUE,
FALSE)
```

And in the value section simply add

```
=FALSE (or TRUE based on your requirement)
```

Comment: This is the one! Adding it to the filter blocked them out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help.